# Reading a config file

Tags: beginner, perl, file

I am relatively new to Perl and would like to check that the code I am writing docent have any major flaws in it or any bad practices.

This is a fairly simple sub but one that gets used often. Seems to work OK. Simply reads a text file that has parameters in it set by the user.

Config.txt

```
#cucm username and password of user associated with phones
username  = bob
password  = bobPass
#subnet details. Use /30 to start with to test 2 phones before entire subnet
subnet = 10.64.97.216/32
#HFS web server details IP and folder
webserver   = http://10.64.164.230/Desktop/
#image file names. Full and Thumbnail size
imgFullSize = screen_F.png
imgThumSize = screen_S.png
```

Perl sub that reads the file:

```
sub readConfigFile
{
print $lfh "Reading Config.txt file\n";
#path to the config file
my $configF = "config.txt";
if($DEBUG == 1){print "opening config File\n";}
open(my $configFhandle, '<', $configF) or die "Unable to open file, $!";
my @arrFileData=<$configFhandle>; #Slurp!

#go through each of the lines in the file
for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#arrFileData; ++$i)
{
local $_ = $arrFileData[$i];
if($DEBUG == 1){print "Reading line:$_";}
#check to see if the line is a comment... if it is skip it
if($_ =~ /^#/)
{
if($DEBUG == 1){print "Line is comment. Skiping:$_";}
next;
}

#split the line into the key and value
my @dataKV = split /=/, $_;
#check to see that Key and Value exist ... if not skip it
my $arrSize = @dataKV;
if($arrSize <= 1)
{
if($DEBUG == 1){print "Read Config: Error: No Key AND Value found:$_";}
next;
}
#remove all leading and end white spaces around elements
s{^\s+|\s+$}{}g foreach @dataKV;

for (my $x = 0; $x <= $#dataKV; $x++)
{
if($DEBUG == 1){print "Key:$dataKV[$x]\n";}
given($dataKV[$x])
{
when (/^username/) 
{
$usr = $dataKV[++$x];
if($DEBUG == 1){print "Value Username:$dataKV[$x]\n";}
next; 
}
when (/^password/) 
{
$pass = $dataKV[++$x];
if($DEBUG == 1){print "Value password:$dataKV[$x]\n";}
next; 
}
when (/^subnet/) 
{
@arrSubnets = $dataKV[++$x];
if($DEBUG == 1){print "Value Subnet:$dataKV[$x]\n";}
next; 
}
when (/^webserver/) 
{ 
$webserver = $dataKV[++$x];
if($DEBUG == 1){print "Value webserver:$dataKV[$x]\n";}
next;
}
when (/^imgFullSize/) 
{ 
$imgFull = $dataKV[++$x];
if($DEBUG == 1){print "Value imgFullSize:$dataKV[$x]\n";}
next
}
when (/^imgThumSize/) 
{ 
$imgThum = $dataKV[++$x];
if($DEBUG == 1){print "Value imgThumSize:$dataKV[$x]\n";}
next
}
}#end of switch statement           
}#end of for loop going through the key and value line
}#end of For loop going though the lines in the config

print "*********************************\n";
print "*Config imported\n";
print "*********************************\n";
print "*username    :$usr\n";
print "*password    :$pass\n";
print "*subnet      :@arrSubnets\n";
print "*webserver   :$webserver\n";
print "*imgFullSize :$imgFull\n";
print "*imgThumSize :$imgThum\n";
print "*********************************\n";
print "Is this above correct?[Y]:";
my $confirm = <>;
if($confirm !~ /^Y/)
{
print $lfh "Config file needs to be changed. Closing script down.\n";
close($lfh) or warn "Unable to close the file handle: $!";
close($configFhandle) or warn "Unable to close the file handle: $!";
print "Script will now terminate. Please amend \"Config.txt\" file and re-run script. Press     any key to terminate";
<>;
exit;
}
#close the file
close($configFhandle) or warn "Unable to close the file handle: $!";
print $lfh "Y pressed by User. Config all good.\n";
}
```

Any advise on how to improve this would be great.

Comment: Can you use CPAN modules? If yes (and it's not an excercise) use [`Config::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::Tiny) or another module for reading ini files.

Comment: @Xaerxess thanks for that and maybe in production i might use that module but more interested in improving my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, here is how I'd write that subroutine. I thoroughly commented the code to explain my choices.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;     # automatic error handling for "open" and other builtins
use IO::Handle;  # object oriented syntax for filehandles

# DEBUG is a compile-time constant initialized by an environment variable.
# If it is false, the debug statements will get optimized away.
use constant DEBUG => $ENV{DEBUG};

# the log file handle and debug file handle
# Here, I opened both to STDERR
open my $lfh, '>&', STDERR;
open my $dfh, '>&', STDERR;

# close the $lfh file handle regardless of how the script terminates.
END {
    no autodie;
    close $lfh or warn "Unable to close the log file handle: $!";
}

# the main part of our script
{
    my $filename = "config.txt";
    # "read_config_file" is a function that takes one argument and returns one value.
    my $config = read_config_file($filename);
    # if the check fails, exit this script with error code "1".
    # the default error code (zero) is considered a success.
    ui_check_config_ok(\*STDOUT, $config, $filename) or exit 1;

    # now we can do stuff with the $config, e.g.
    my $usr = $config->{username};
}

# Name your variables in snake_case, not with camelCase.
# This function *only* parses the config file.
# It does not interact with the user.
# Such separation of concern makes your code easier to maintain:
# every function should do one thing only.
sub read_config_file {
    # Subroutines can take an argument list.
    # We unpack it like this:
    my ($filename) = @_;

    $lfh->say("Reading config file $filename");
    DEBUG and $dfh->say("Opening config file $filename");

    my %known_keys = map { $_ => 1 } qw/
        username password subnet webserver imgFullSize imgThumSize
    /;

    # we wills store the config in this hash
    my %config;

    open my $fh, "<", $filename;

    # don't slurp the file, we loop over it line by line
    LINE:
    while (<$fh>) {
        # trim the line
        s{\A\s+}{};
        s{\s+\z}{};

        DEBUG and $dfh->say("Reading line: $_");
        if (/^#/) {
            DEBUG and $dfh->say("Line is comment, skipping.");
            next LINE;
        }

        # * We use the /x flag on regexes to be able to structure the regex with spaces
        #   they won't match, they're just decoration
        # * instead of assigning to an array, we assign to a list of scalars.
        #   If the "split" fails, the last one should be "undef"
        # * We only accept one "=" per line, and produce 2 fragments max. So
        #       foo = bar = baz
        #   will produce $key="foo", $value="bar = baz".
        my ($key, $value) = split m{\s* [=] \s*}x, $_, 2;
        if (not defined $value) {
            DEBUG and $dfh->say("Ignoring config error: no key = value pair found on line: $_");
            next LINE;
        }

        DEBUG and $dfh->say("Value $key:$value");
        $config{$key} = $value;

        # a sanity check – you don't do anything on unknown keys
        if (not exists $known_keys{$key}) {
            $lfh->say("The config provided the unknown key $key, ignoring.")
        }
    }

    # another sanity check – did the user forget to specify some properties?
    for my $key (keys %known_keys) {
        if (not exists $config{$key}) {
            $lfh->say("The config didn't provide a key $key, ignoring.")
        }
    }

    return \%config;
}

# another subroutine that provides the user interface to ask whether the data is correct
# It will return a truth value whether the config was OK.
sub ui_check_config_ok {
    # Here, we see an argument list with three values
    my ($ui_fh, $config, $filename) = @_;

    $ui_fh->say($_) for
        "*********************************",
        "*Config imported",
        "*********************************",
        "*username    :$config->{username}",
        "*password    :$config->{password}",
        "*subnet      :$config->{subnet}",
        "*webserver   :$config->{webserver}",
        "*imgFullSize :$config->{imgFullSize}",
        "*imgThumSize :$config->{imgThumSize}",
        "*********************************";
    $ui_fh->print("Is this above correct?[Y]:");
    if (<STDIN> =~ /^\s*Y/) {
        $lfh->say("The user pressed Y. Config is good.");
        return 1;
    }

    $lfh->say("Config file contains false information, please correct.");
    $lfh->say("Terminating script");
    $ui_fh->say("The script will now terminate.");
    $ui_fh->say("Please amend the file $filename and rerun the script.");
    $ui_fh->say("Press any key to terminate...");
    <>;
    return 0;
}
```

Note how indentation made this code much easier to read than the dump you provided. Please use indentation!

I actually do not generally use `IO::Handle`, but it makes stuff more obvious when having more than one file handle. The `autodie` module is a bit inflexible, but I highly encourage it when you are still new with Perl, as it provides sensible defaults. You do not manually have to close file handles if they are variables declared with `my` – they will get closed automatically, and it's highly unlikely that closing a file will fail (file handles are not only used for physical files, but also for other things like pipes, where the `close` can fail).

Comment: thanks for that (especially for the comments) It will take me some time to digest all the information but this is exactly the feedback i was looking for.